# Question for the estimation of $\sum_{i=1}^x \frac{1}{w+i}$ as $x \to \infty$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, approximation, estimation, riemann-sum

I have a question of the estimation of this summation:
$$ \frac{1}{w+1}+\frac{1}{w+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{w+x}$$

Which is:
$$\sum_{i=1}^x \frac{1}{w+i}$$

What I have tried: applying limit to the summation:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty }\sum_{i=1}^x \frac{1}{w+i}$$

Which becomes:
$$\int_1^x \frac{1}{w+y}\,dy$$

Which equals:
$$\ln{(w+x)}-\ln{(w+1)}$$

However, I found that my answer is wrong and other people's answer is:
$$\ln(w+x)-\ln(w)$$

If I try this in MS Excel, the error for my answer is bigger than the others.

Can anyone explain at which part I did it wrong?
And what is the name for this approximation? Is it Riemann sum approximation?

Thank you! I am sorry if this is a duplicate. I tried to search but I didn't find any duplicate for this specific question.

Comment: You just need to integrate from 0 to $x$.

Comment: Why do I need to integrate from 0 and not 1? The sigma notation is from 1 to x. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: The summation is the area of the rectangles under the function $\frac{1}{w+x}$ over the interval $[0,x]$.

Comment: Thank you! You even added an answer to explain this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $w>-1$ and $x \in \mathbb{N}$.

One may recall the classic identity
$$
\Gamma(y+1)=y \:\Gamma(y),\quad y>0. \tag1
$$ from which, setting $\psi (y):= \left(\log \Gamma (y) \right)'$, one deduces 
$$
\psi(y+1)-\psi(y)=\frac1y,\quad y>0. \tag2
$$ Next, putting  $y=w+k$ and summing $(2)$ from $k=1$ to $k=x$, terms telescope, one gets
$$
\sum_{k=1}^x\frac1{w+k}=\psi(w+x+1)-\psi(w+1). \tag3
$$ Then, as $x \to \infty$, one may use the [digamma asymptotic expansion](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm)
${\bf 6.3.18}$:
$$
\psi(x+1)=\ln x+O\left( \frac1x\right)
$$ yielding, as $x \to \infty$,

> $$
> \sum_{k=1}^x\frac1{w+k}=\ln x-\psi(w+1) +O\left( \frac1x\right).
> $$

Comment: Thank you for answering, I will try to learn your solution, I haven't studied digamma yet.

Comment: Can you explain why $\psi(w+x+1)$ becomes $\psi(x+1)$ in the last equation? Thank you very much!

Comment: @RandomInteger Sure. In fact, as $x \to \infty$, you have $\psi(w+x+1)=\ln(w+x+1)+O(\frac{1}{w+x+1})$ but $O(\frac{1}{w+x+1})=O(\frac{1}{x})$ also, since $\ln(1+u)\sim u$ as $u \to 0$, then $\ln(w+x+1)=\ln(x(1+\frac{w+1}{x}))=\ln x+\ln(1+\frac{w+1}{x})=\ln x +O(\frac1{x})$, where we have set $u=\frac1{x}$. Hoping it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time, now it becomes clearer :).

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use harmonic numbers since  $$S_x=\sum_{i=1}^x \frac{1}{w+i}=H_{w+x}-H_w$$ Now, using the asymptotics you would get $$S_x=\left(\log \left(x\right)+\gamma-H_w
   \right)+\frac{w+\frac{1}{2}}{x}-\frac{6 w^2+6 w+1}{12
   x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$

For illustration purposes, using $w=123$ and $x=456$, the exact result would be $\approx 1.54592$ while the abovea pproximation gives $\approx 1.54041$

Comment: Thank you! Glad I posted my problem to this site. I don't have anyone to consult to near to me in real life. By the way, I have checked harmonic numbers on Wikipedia, but I am still lost at this O and $\gamma$.

Comment: You are very welcome !

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{x}\frac{1}{w+i}=\text{area of rectangles}\leq\int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{w+t}dt=\ln\left(w+x\right)-\ln\left(w\right)
$$

Comment: Thank you! This explains why the integral starts from 0.